# Dummy Packet Shown in pcap file

Tags: metadata, wireshark, packet-capture, ns-3

I am new to ns3. I want to send custom data from node 1 to node 2(say a string) in UDP Echo Application. I am creating the packet, adding header and trailer, and the tags. I have also enabled metadata. I have used the code provided in other threads here to add the data into packet. (stringstream msg..........;     ). But I am unable to view the data in the pcap, all I see is zeroes, so basically dummy packet is getting displayed. I have followed this link :

: http://www.nsnam.org/support/faq/miscellaneous/

Could anybody please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 0):

You should check "example/tutorial2.cc" to understand how to send a custom UDP package and generate pcap file from it.
http://www.nsnam.org/doxygen/second_8cc_source.html